# Send push notifications for Windows Phone with a certificate?

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone, ssl-certificate, mpns

I would like to send push notifications for Windows Phone. I have a sending program and client app, but now it works without a certificate. I want to use a certificate in order to avoid the limit of 500 pushes per day.

What should I do to use a certificate? Where can I get a certificate and what should I do in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certificate from any certificate signing authority. You'll need to upload this certificate in your account at Windows Phone developer centre. You can find more information here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941099%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)